# What's wrong with my Vector stopping all of a sudden?

Tags: c++, if-statement, vector, string-comparison

I'm getting an error after it loops to element 4096.  For some reason, it stops there and just causes error.  Any idea?

```
if(myFile.is_open()){

    while(getline(myFile, linePerLine) && cacheSizeVector.size() <= userInputCacheSize){

        cacheSizeVector.push_back(linePerLine);

        if (find(cacheSizeVector.begin(), cacheSizeVector.end(), linePerLine) != cacheSizeVector.end()){
            for(int i = 0; i <= userInputCacheSize; i++){
                if(cacheSizeVector[i] == linePerLine){    <<<<LINE OF ERROR!
                    lruCounter[i] = lruCounter[i] + 1;
                    cout << lruCounter[i] << endl;
                    cout << cacheSizeVector[i] << " HIT!" << endl;
                    cout << cacheSizeVector.size() << endl << endl;
                }
            }

        }
        else{
            std::cout << "Element not found in myvector\n";
        }
```

Some error that were initialized:

"{return __is_long() ? __get_long_size() : __get_short_size();}" << EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: First things first: did you break on the line, where the _error_ occurred, with a debugger, and investigated the values of the local variables? In addition: Please manufacture [mcve]. My hunch is: you are accessing the `vector` out of bounds.

Comment: Did you make sure that `userInputCacheSize` is not bigger than your `cacheSizeVector` size?

Comment: @KyleKhalaf Yea, that was the problem!  I changed it to cacheSizeVector.size();.  Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the vector using an out of bounds index in the loop.

```
        for(int i = 0; i <= userInputCacheSize; i++){
            if(cacheSizeVector[i] == linePerLine){    <<<<LINE OF ERROR!
                lruCounter[i] = lruCounter[i] + 1;
                cout << lruCounter[i] << endl;
                cout << cacheSizeVector[i] << " HIT!" << endl;
                cout << cacheSizeVector.size() << endl << endl;
            }
        }
```

Use of `i <= userInputCacheSize` in the conditional of the for loop is not right. It should be:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < cacheSizeVector.size(); i++){
```

Of course, that assumes that `i` will be a valid index to access the elements of `lruCounter`. If that is not the case, you have to change your code accordingly.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the help!   That was problem... such an easy fix and tips.  I spent hours trying to figure it out.  Thank goodness I joined StackOverflow!

Comment: @AndresValdez, you are welcome. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: Hey sorry to bother.  I came across something very similar.  It doesn't stop at 4096 anymore, but now it stops at 16384.  Same error and everything.  The code is basically the same, but just changed what you told me "userCacheSize" to -> "cacheSizeVector.size()".

Comment: @AndresVal, it's difficult for me to see what could be wrong without looking at the entire program. Try using a debugger.